# Django - Going back to a directory at a upper level from the template with href in django

Tags: django

trying to keep the question simple!

I am currently in the directory which has a template **cart.html**:

> 8000/shop/cart/6/M/user

and I want to go to the directory:

> 8000/shop/shirts

So I just wrote in the **cart.html**:

```
<a href="{% url 'shop' 'shirts' %}">
```

Which gives me an error:

> Reverse for 'shop' not found. 'shop' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

So, I believe that its because I am trying to go from a lower directory back into a higher directory in the hierarchy so is there a way I can edit the *href* in **cart.html** in order to go to the shirts directory?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Read the docs for the `url` tag. The first argument (`shop`) should be the `name` you give to your route in your `urls.py`. Django doesn't care about the hierarchy (except `include`s) you have in the path.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the urls. you can chose a name to use whenever into a django template, to reffer to this url

```
path('shirts/',views.shirts,name='shirts'),
```

now, inside a template

```
<a href="{% url 'shirts' %}">Shirts</a>
```

The name after the url within the '' is the NAME you define into your urls file

Comment: Okay got you, I always questioned what is the use of that name parameter, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

you can go to parent directory by `..` so `<a href='../../../shirts'>` would be what you want,
or without changing the directory `<a href='/shop/shirts'>`.

but it's better to use `{% url 'url-name' %}`